# Menu Horizontal em Collapse com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Estou fazendo um menu horizontal, no qual o submenu vai ser aberto em collapse ao clicar no link pai. Porém não estou conseguindo fazer o submenu abrir com jquery ao clicar no link pai. Neste exemplo, o link pai com submenu é o "Menu 1", ao clicar nele não aparece o submenu.

```js
$(".menu-item-has-children a").removeAttr("href");
$('.menu-categorias-container li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').show();
$('.menu-categorias-container li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('href');
  var element = $(this).parent('li');
  if (element.hasClass('open')) {
    element.removeClass('open');
    element.find('li').removeClass('open');
    element.find('ul').slideUp(200);
  } else {
    element.addClass('open');
    element.children('ul').slideDown(200);
    element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp(200);
    element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
    element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
    element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp(200);
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-categorias-container,
.menu-categorias-container ul,
.menu-categorias-container ul li,
.menu-categorias-container ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu-categorias-container {
  width: 220px;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.menu-categorias-container > ul > li.active > ul {
  display: block;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
.menu-categorias-container > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #3ab4a6;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
.menu-categorias-container > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #d8f3f0;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 26px;
  top: 19px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  top: 23px;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul > li.menu-item-has-children.open > a:after,
.menu-categorias-container ul > li.menu-item-has-children.open > a:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-categorias-container ul ul li a {
  padding: 14px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
  background: #49505a;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 32px;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a:after {
  top: 16px;
  right: 26px;
  background: #ddd;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a:before {
  top: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-categorias-container">
  
  <ul id="menu-categorias" class="menu">
  
    <li id="menu-item-1631" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children">
      <a href="https://www.google.com.br/">Menu 1</a>
      
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        
          <li id="menu-item-1648" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1648">
            <a href="https://www.google.com.br/imghp?hl=pt-BR&tab=wi">
              Submenu 1
            </a>
          </li>
          
          <li id="menu-item-1632" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1632">
            <a href="https://www.google.com.br/imghp?hl=pt-BR&tab=wi">
              Submenu 2
            </a>
          </li>
          
          <li id="menu-item-1629" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1629">
            <a href="https://www.google.com.br/imghp?hl=pt-BR&tab=wi">
              Submenu 3
            </a>
          </li>
          
        </ul>
        
    </li>
    
    <li id="menu-item-1640" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1640">
      <a href="https://www.google.com.br/">
        Menu 2
      </a>
    </li>
    
    <li id="menu-item-1641" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1641">
      <a href="https://www.google.com.br/">
        Menu 3
      </a>
    </li>
  
  </ul>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltou vc colocar a classe `has-sub` na `LI` que tem `sub-menu`... Fazendo isso já funciona normalmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$(".menu-item-has-children a").removeAttr("href");
$('.menu-categorias-container li.active').addClass('open').children('ul').show();
$('.menu-categorias-container li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('href');
  var element = $(this).parent('li');
  if (element.hasClass('open')) {
    element.removeClass('open');
    element.find('li').removeClass('open');
    element.find('ul').slideUp(200);
  } else {
    element.addClass('open');
    element.children('ul').slideDown(200);
    element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp(200);
    element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
    element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
    element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp(200);
  }
});
```

```css
.menu-categorias-container,
.menu-categorias-container ul,
.menu-categorias-container ul li,
.menu-categorias-container ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.menu-categorias-container {
  width: 220px;
  font-family: Raleway, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.menu-categorias-container > ul > li.active > ul {
  display: block;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
.menu-categorias-container > ul > li > a {
  padding: 16px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  background: #3ab4a6;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
.menu-categorias-container > ul > li > a:hover {
  color: #d8f3f0;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a:after {
  position: absolute;
  right: 26px;
  top: 19px;
  z-index: 5;
  display: block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a:before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 22px;
  top: 23px;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #ffffff;
  content: "";
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul > li.menu-item-has-children.open > a:after,
.menu-categorias-container ul > li.menu-item-has-children.open > a:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.menu-categorias-container ul ul li a {
  padding: 14px 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ddd;
  background: #49505a;
  -webkit-transition: color .2s ease;
  -o-transition: color .2s ease;
  transition: color .2s ease;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 32px;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul ul li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a:after {
  top: 16px;
  right: 26px;
  background: #ddd;
}
.menu-categorias-container ul ul > li.menu-item-has-children > a:before {
  top: 20px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu-categorias-container">
  
  <ul id="menu-categorias" class="menu">
  
    <li id="menu-item-1631" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children has-sub">
      <a href="https://www.google.com.br/">Menu 1</a>
      
        <ul class="sub-menu">
        
          <li id="menu-item-1648" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1648">
            <a href="https://www.google.com.br/imghp?hl=pt-BR&tab=wi">
              Submenu 1
            </a>
          </li>
          
          <li id="menu-item-1632" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1632">
            <a href="https://www.google.com.br/imghp?hl=pt-BR&tab=wi">
              Submenu 2
            </a>
          </li>
          
          <li id="menu-item-1629" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1629">
            <a href="https://www.google.com.br/imghp?hl=pt-BR&tab=wi">
              Submenu 3
            </a>
          </li>
          
        </ul>
        
    </li>
    
    <li id="menu-item-1640" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1640">
      <a href="https://www.google.com.br/">
        Menu 2
      </a>
    </li>
    
    <li id="menu-item-1641" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-1641">
      <a href="https://www.google.com.br/">
        Menu 3
      </a>
    </li>
  
  </ul>
  
</div>
```